# How to use .loc while creating a new column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df.loc[:,'C'] = df.apply(lambda row: min(row['A'],row['B']) if row['A'] > 0 else max(row['B'],0),axis=1)
```

I'm creating a new variable 'C' in the dataframe df. I'm getting the slicing error inspite of using the .loc function. How do I fix it?

```
/opt/python/python35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:362: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[key] = _infer_fill_value(value)
/opt/python/python35/lib/python3.5/site- 
packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:543: SettingWithCopyWarning: 

A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas- 
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
self.obj[item] = s
```

Answer (score 0):

Link to docs [loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)

```
df.loc[:,'C']=df.apply(lambda row: min(row['A'],row['B']) if row['A'] > 0 else max(row['B'],0),axis=1)
```

Comment: what is the error? It works on my local considering a simple example. Edit your post with proper input and the error you are getting.Thanks